# Paraview: represent as vector field

Tags: paraview

I've got a VTK file with a regular grid on which I have a vector field F (Fx, Fy and Fy) and a scalar field (G).

I would like to do a "quiver plot" as the following picture, but in 3D. Is it possible ?

[image: quiver plot]

After this, I would like to wrap the field G by the vector field F. Once again, is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping a field by another field?

Comment: I'd like to advect a scalar field A following the vectorial field B, defined on the same grid.

Comment: I think you are looking for the paraview filter WarpByVector.

Comment: I do, however my Fx, Fy and Fz fields are defined as three scalar fields and WarpByVector expects 1 vector field. Is there a way to tell paraview to treat the 3 scalars as 1 vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your vector components are stored as scalar arrays, then you can do the following:

1. Create a vector using a Calculator Filter: comp_x x iHat + comp_y x jHat + comp_z x kHat
2. On this result you can apply the WarpByVector filter